# How to update javascript file in client browser?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

When I have bug in javascript file I fix it and deploy.
But to have updated file in browser I should press Ctrl+F5.

It is not an issue for me, but it is difficult to say to user to update files.

**How to make user browser to update javascript file from server without special actions?**

One of the approaches is to add to path to js file revision of file - every time file path will be different. But this is not convenient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What many sites do is add a URL parameter on the URL pointing to the javascript file and change it every time that the file changes.

Something like this:

```
<script langauge="javascript" src="myfile.js?ver=1" />
```

And after a change:

```
<script langauge="javascript" src="myfile.js?ver=2" />
```

It may not be convenient, but it is the most common solution. Some web frameworks automate this process so the developer does not have to manually increment the version number.

Comment: For example `/path/to/javascript.js?123456789`

Comment: thanks. just one drawback is to update all js file inclusions on deployment.

Comment: @sergdev - If you use an identical version number for all files, you can use search replace...

Comment: consider this use case: what if user is has open a webpage and is idle for 10 mins...in mean time, you update a JS file. How will you push the new JS file to client side without any action?

Comment: @Viral - I wouldn't, not this way. If this was a real requirement, one could do this with long polling of the server to check and replace the file (with appropriate checks that the client will not break when this changeover happens).

Comment: @Oded thanks..it not real requirement but I was asked in interview and I gave the similar answer as you have written. I just wanted to explore different ways as interviewer asked me

Comment: How would I red this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Add a random query string at the end, like SO does ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/js/master.min.js?v=d761eb59f537"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change name of file with javascript. I'm adding version number to do that: for example I'm changing scripts1.2.js to scripts1.3.js

Answer (score 0):

just add any param to url

```
mysite/javascript/myscript.js?ver=1
```

and checnge this param with new version.